# WebCenter Sites tutorials?

Tags: content-management-system, webcenter, webcenter-sites

I am new to CMS.
All i could find on WebCenter sites is developer guide and some youtube videos provided by oracle, which was not much of a help for starters.

Can someone please provide any helpful links? (like steps to create a site)

Is Oracle WebCenter Sites is used widely?

Comment: There really isn't a lot of documentation out there, but WebCenter sites is taking off like a rocket. With Oracle behind it, there is a lot of interest out there.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a very extensive documentation. If you are planning to learn from scratch, Try to get a copy of JumpStart Kit which would be available through Oracle Support Portal(you should have a valid support identifier to download JSK).

And yes, WCS is used widely but not as much as wordpress or Joomla.